# Looking for the title of this may be Mexican music

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

I think I had played this music 25 years ago, when I was living in Mexico.
It sounds like a Mexican traditional song, or Mariachi.

I can only remember the phrase written in the score bellow.
It's likely that whole music is constructed of similar phrases.
I played it with my violin (with few others from violin class),
but it is possible that this is usually played by a guitar or trumpet part.
I don't know if it has singing on this music.

Key might not be correct.

[image: the score I restored from my memory]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the crown jewel of the Mexican repertoir: Huapango, composed by José Pablo Moncayo.

The violins start playing the theme of your first two lines right after the 1 minute mark in [this performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HAmrz3-ehI).

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly the one I was looking for!